# Failed to initialize end point associated with ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]

Tags: java, eclipse

Can someone help me?

```
GRAVE: Failed to initialize end point associated with ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: timeout < 0
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.setSoTimeout(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:162)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.bind(NioEndpoint.java:352)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.init(AbstractEndpoint.java:823)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init(AbstractProtocol.java:476)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:960)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initInternal(StandardService.java:568)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.initInternal(StandardServer.java:871)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:592)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:615)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:578)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.load(Bootstrap.java:308)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:482)

fev. 04, 2023 9:26:28 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService initInternal
GRAVE: Failed to initialize connector [Connector[AJP/1.3-8009]]
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to initialize component [Connector[AJP/1.3-8009]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initInternal(StandardService.java:568)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.initInternal(StandardServer.java:871)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:592)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:615)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:578)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.load(Bootstrap.java:308)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:482)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Protocol handler initialization failed
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:962)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: timeout < 0
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.setSoTimeout(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:162)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.bind(NioEndpoint.java:352)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.init(AbstractEndpoint.java:823)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init(AbstractProtocol.java:476)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:960)
    ... 11 more
```

I have no idea what it could be, can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

You are probably hitting this Tomcat bug: https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=63814

> Socket timeout -1 no longer allowed since Java 13, leading to IllegalArgumentException and unit test hang for TestAbstractAjpProcessor

From the [Tomcat 7 changelog](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/changelog.html), it was fixed in version 7.0.98.

> 63814: Do not set server socket timeout with negative values in NIO. (remm)

Since Java 13, `setSoTimeout()`'s behaviour [was changed](https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8221248) to explicitly throw an exception when a socket timeout was set to negative.

---

My guess is that you are running a very old version of Tomcat (< 7.0.98) with a newer version of Java (>= 13).  Either upgrade Tomcat to a more recent version or downgrade your JDK to 12 or older.

If you need to use the particular versions you are using now, you could try explicitly [setting the socket timeout configuration option](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/http.html) to a positive value on the connector in Tomcat configuration file `conf/server.xml`.